# TouchImageView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, touchimageview

I have a TouchImageView inside ScrollView but when I zoom the imageview and try to swipe up/down the response comes from the ScrollView.
Is there any way to stop the ScrollView when I touch on TouchImageView